# Dynamic "itemSize" specified in a storyboard on UICollectionView based on new iOS 8 Size Classes

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

How can I set different "itemSize" on UICollectionView for different size classes. e.g. I want to have different itemSize for iPad and iPhones defined in one storyboard.

thanks

Comment: `itemSize` is a display-only property and doesn't affect the constraints or size of your cells. You can define the size you want in `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`